# First time a text Input is selected, delete its value

Tags: jquery, input

When an element is clicked for the first time, I would like its value to be set to empty.

Does the IF function work in jQuery?  Is it like JavaScript?

I only want the data to be erased on the first time, of course, because it will be deleting the default value.

**HTML**

```
<input id="Name" class="inputLight" type="text" value="Enter your name here.">
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').click(function() {
var $this = $(this),
    clickNum = $this.data('clickNum');

if (!clickNum) clickNum = 1;

if(clickNum =1)$this.value = "";

$this.data('clickNum', ++clickNum);
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need any if statements. You simply want to bind an event which will only be executed once.

Use jQuery's [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method:

```
$('input').one('focus', function(){
    this.value = '';
});
```

Comment: I love simple, elegant solutions.